Can arbitrary commans appear during suboption negotiation (telnet)?
Inside a subnegotiation, a IAC is generally allowed, at least for IAC SE and IAC IAC.
How is the semantic of any other IAC command?
Does it have to be evaluated recursively?
Is it even possible to nest subnegotiation?
